# How to get set or get children class private property with a late bind instance in php?

Tags: php

In father class,

```
    public function autoAssignValue($data)
{
    //var_dump($this);
    if(is_array($data)){
        foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }
}
    public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $this->$name = $value;
}
    public function __get($name)
{
    return $this->$name;
}
```

The children class trying to set some private property through super class  assignValue($data)

It is impossible to do this in this way.

I var_dump($this) , sure it is son class.

how to solve this problem, any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: all son class instance is late binding

Answer (score 0):

It seems only two ways to solve:
1. change private to protected in children class,
2. implement the __set() __get() function in children class
any other ideas?